# How to select char_length of (select ...) in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have to select char length of string which I can get by another select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_SCHEMA) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LIMIT 0, 1
```

returns

```
TABLE_SCHEMA
mysql
```

Now I want to get char_length of this `mysql` and make it in one query.

These queries

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_SCHEMA) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LIMIT 0, 1)
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(DISTINCT(TABLE_SCHEMA) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LIMIT 0, 1)
```

return syntax error.

So how to this create query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with: if you a just looking for the list of databases, you want to use `information_schema.schemata` instead of `information_schema.tables`. This avoids the need to use `DISTINCT`, and then you can simply do:

```
SELECT schema_name, CHAR_LENGTH(schema_name) schema_name_length
FROM information_schema.schemata
LIMIT 0, 1
```

NB: `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause is not a good practice. You cannot predict which records will come up first.

---

If for some reason you do want to stick to your current query, then you would need to turn it to a subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, CHAR_LENGTH(TABLE_SCHEMA) TABLE_SCHEMA_LENGTH
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(TABLE_SCHEMA) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LIMIT 0, 1
) x
```